# Thymeleaf display HashMap

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, hashmap, thymeleaf

It may be a silly qustion, but I still cannot find an answer to it.

My Spring Boot application looks something like this:

**Model:**

```
public class Company {

public static final String URL_COMPANY = "http://193.142.112.220:8337/companyList";
private Long iD;
private String companyName;
public static Map<Long, Object> companyMap;

public Long getiD() {
    return iD;
}

public void setiD(Long iD) {
    this.iD = iD;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return companyName;
}}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller

public class UrlController {

@GetMapping("/success")
public String show(Model model) {

    HashMap<Long, Object> company = (HashMap<Long, Object>) Company.companyMap;
    model.addAttribute("companyID", company);
    return "success";
}
```

**View:**

```
<h1>All Companies:</h1>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="mapEntry: ${companyID}">
        <td th:text="${mapEntry.key}"></td>
        <td th:text="${mapEntry.value}"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
<a th:href="@{/}">Homepage</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So my goal is to display a table filled with Company ID's and Names. Even though, my model gets a map, I still can't see it in my browser. The table is empty.

```
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="mapEntry: {1=Tire Systems, 2=IT Enterprise, 3=Car Manufacture, 4=Electro Market}">
        <td th:text=""></td>
        <td th:text=""></td>

    </tr>
```

This is what i get if i check the page source. So I clearly see, that map is loaded, but not displayed.

Moreover, a link with "homepage" does not work, and i am not sure why?

What am I missing? I am trying to fill a table with Companies, and then, using Id's of those companies, show materials attached to company via this ID. Can i use hyperlinks in table for Id's?

Comment: Looks like thymeleaf isn't being evaluated, and it's just doing regular JSTL.  If thymeleaf was running, the attributes "th:each" and "th:text" would not appear in the source.  It's just evaluating the`${...}` expressions.

Comment: So you suggest a lack of dependecy in .pom file?

Comment: What does your Thymeleaf Config look like? Could you post that aswell? Look like a resolving/config problem to me.

Comment: Actually the problem is solved. When setting a new spring boot project, I didn't include thymeleaf as an option. So as @Metroids said, it was not evaluated. Adding a thymeleaf option in config solved the problem. A silly mistake of the begginer.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display a map. IF value of your map is a POJO Try something like followings

```
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr th:each="mapEntry : ${companyID}">
    <td th:text="${mapEntry.key}">keyvalue</td>
    <td th:each="item : ${mapEntry.value}" th:text="${item.FIELD_NAME_OF_YOUR_POJO}">keyvalue</td>
</tr>
```

This should work. What i tried to show is, it is possible. The iteration depends on your data structure. If you have complex data structure iteration will change accordingly.

If value of your map is a primitive type or java reference type your current code should work. I have executed similar code like your's and it worked without any trouble. Please have a look -

```
 HashMap<Long, Object> company = new HashMap<>();
 company.put(1L, "Hello World");
 model.addAttribute("companyID", company);
```

If value of your map is custom java type. Then follow the previous snippet.